# Homeomorphism between subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

I have two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $X$ and $Y$ defined as $X=\{(x,y,t) \mid x^2+y^2=1,t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $Y= \{(0,e,t) \mid e^2=1,t \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic? Are $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash X$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash Y$ homeomorphic?

For the first one, i think the fundamental groups are not same so they can't be homeomorphic.

Comment: $X$ is just an infinite hollow cylinder, $S^1\times\Bbb R$, and $Y$ is two parallel lines in $\Bbb R^3$; if you can see that, you should have no trouble following Seirios’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash Y$ are connected whereas $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash X$ are not connected.